Should the for-beginners tag be retained?
I recently added a "for-beginners" tag because I thought it was important to the site; my view at the time was that too many answers (and questions) are beyond the understanding of beginners.
I've since read this:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/
which discourages the use of a "beginner" tag.
I'm not sure that this changes my view though, given the highly technical nature of how bitcoins work. I can still see value in it.
However, I'm willing to go with what the community wants, and remove that tag if others don't want it. So, is the Bitcoin site a special case that needs that tag, or should it go?

Related: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-does-the-basics-tag-mean?rq=1

I don't really have anything to add in addition to what's in that blog post but the fact that  it is so clearly discouraged by StackExchange is enough for me to suggest that we remove it. A lot of experience from StackOverflow went into that decision and I don't think that our site is that different from SO.

There’s no reason these sites need to repeat all the mistakes we made with tagging two years ago — we can do it better each time for each new community, and feed those improvements back into the entire network.


Please delete this tag quickly. This meta-tag satisfies both 1 and 2:

the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question
means different things to different people

Issues are already there. This question has virtually no tag. The meta-tag will ease access to off-topic questions, multiple unrelated questions in a single post, etc.

I've removed it from all questions, though I'm not sure I entirely agree with it satisfying condition 2 any more than many other tags do. It could also be argued that it would make sense on its own, but it's not a debate I care to continue, and I'd probably lose anyway for other reasons I haven't figured out yet...
